# Does layout-sw600dp not work with emulators?

Tags: android

I think I remember someone saying that emulators will not pull from `layout-sw600dp` folders?

Is this true as mine is not doing it.

I am using API level 14.

Comment: What's the configuration of your emulator?

Answer (score 0):

It will work, i have used "layout-sw600dp-land".

Go for it , and also you can see your changes in eclipse graphical layout window.